# Question on Oracle Public DB link inside Procedures

Tags: oracle

Scenario : 
A procedure 'XYZ' is created with DB account 'SCOTT'. The procedure uses a public DB link to connect to another database.
We have another user 'EVE' who has access to execute procedures owned by 'SCOTT'. 
If procedure XYZ is executed by EVE , how does the public DB link inside the procedure work? Does it use the credentials of SCOTT to connect to Target DB ( the owner) or does it use the credentials of EVE ( the executor)?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how the link was set up. A public link means it is accessible to anyone to access the link but the credentials used to access the remote DB can either be those of the current user or a specific user.

Take a look at [CREATE DATABASE LINK](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5005.htm) for the full syntax and explanations.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. 
I understand that below is how a Public DB link will work - the database link connects to the remote database as the locally connected user. My question is specifically if a public DB link is used inside a procedure - does the DB link connection use the credentials of the procedure owner or does it tries to use the credentials of the user who executes the procedure? 
Note : The public DB link was created with no additional clauses like CONNECT TO CURRENT_USER or connecting with user and password (Fixed user DB link)

Comment: The fact that it is a public DBLink is a red herring. The connection in your case will be done by the connected user - EVE. EVE will need permissions on the objects in the remote database in order to use them. However, with things like this you can always set up a test to see what happens.